# If $x$ is real and $x + \frac1x$ is rational, show by strong induction that $x^n + \frac{1}{x^n}$ is rational for all $n$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Suppose that $x$ subset of Real numbers such that $x + \frac{1}{x}$ is subset of Rational numbers. Using strong induction, show that for each $n$ subset of Natural numbers, $A_n = x^n + \frac{1}{x^n}$   is subset of Rational numbers.

How do I start? I was given a hint of the product of $A_1$ and $A_n$ but have no idea how to apply.

thanks in advance!

Comment: If $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x+\frac{1}{x}\in\mathbb{Q}$ it follows that $x\in\mathbb{Q}$. But then $x^n,\frac{1}{x^n}\in\mathbb{Q}$, and therefore $A_n\in\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: thanks! the answer is basically right in front of me, I was thinking too hard!

Comment: Please note that you should not say that, for example, $x$ is a **subset** of the real numbers. You could say that $x$ is an element* of the set of real numbers, but it is better to say $x$ is a real number. Same with the rationals part.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use strong induction: Using the hint $$ A_1 A_n = x^{n+1}+\frac{1}{x^{n+1}} +x^{n-1}+\frac{1}{x^{n-1}} = A_{n+1} + A_{n-1}. $$ You want to rearrange this for an expression in $A_{n+1}$, the answer should follow from strong induction.